# Changing the Modulo congruence base?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is a conversion someone on SE made:

$$77777\equiv1\pmod{4}\implies77777^{77777}\equiv77777^1\equiv7\pmod{10}$$

But I don't understand how this is done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the last digit of $77777^{77777}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155705/find-the-last-digit-of-7777777777)

Comment: @Macavity Not really duplicate. More of a follow-up question which could have been asked in a comment to the respective answer.

Comment: @AlexR Agreed, though the OP has a pattern of doing this.

Comment: @Macavity, is it wrong to have follow up questions?

Comment: Not really, though the appropriate place for a clarification on the same question / answer is not somewhere else.

Comment: If I have small questions, on which I dont need that much clarifiation is the comments. Otherwise I always beleived a new question.

Answer (score 5):

What was actually used is [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):
$$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
Where $\varphi$ is the [totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). $\varphi(10) = 4$ so
$$77777^{a + 4k} \equiv 77777^a \pmod{10}\\
\Rightarrow 77777^{77777} \equiv 77777^{77777 \bmod 4} = 77777^1 \pmod{10}$$

Comment: (+1) Why did you specifically find: $\varphi(10)$?

Comment: @Lebes Because we want to compute $77777^{77777} \pmod{10}$ so we need the value of $\varphi(10)$ so we can apply Euler's theorem.

Comment: this answer more directly answers the question, though the other approach is important to understand as well.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $7^2\equiv -1\pmod{10}$.

No base change actually happens.

Comment: The person uses $\pmod{4}$ though

Comment: Yes, I used $\pmod 2$ to give a little bit less away - and then I added the second sentence to hint at how the first might be used.

Comment: ,Can you show me a full explanation? It isnt homework, I am just trying to under modular arithemtic? +1

Comment: I like Henrik's style (+1). @Lebes, why don't you continue this and calculate the remainders mod $10$ for the next few powers of $7$?!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I did and got: $$77777^{n} \equiv 77777^{n + 4} \pmod{10}$$ but I dont know what to do next/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you. That actually made me feel really good about my answer.

Comment: Rinse and repeat. $$7777^0\equiv 7777^4\equiv7777^8\ldots$$ All modulo 10.

Comment: @Lebes: When you've realised that $77777^n\equiv 77777^{n+4}$ it should be easy to find a $k$ such that $77777^n\equiv 77777^m$ where $n\equiv m\pmod{k}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, so: $$77777^{n} \equiv 77777^{n + 4k}$$ for integer $k$. Let $n = 1$. $$77777 \equiv 77777^{1 + 4k}$$

Let $$77777 = 1 + 4k \rightarrow k = 19444$$

$$77777 \equiv 77777^{77777} \equiv 7$$ Then?

Comment: @Lebes: That's correct. To summarize: You noticed that the last digits of the sequence $7777^n$ repeats in a cycle of length four. Therefore the members with $n=7777$ and $n=1$ share the last digit. With $n=1$ the task of calculating it is trivial :-)